# Dropping a column from a data.frame causes unwanted loss of an attribute

Tags: r, dataframe, attr

I want to drop a column from a data.frame.  But when I do, an attribute of the data.frame is lost, which I don't want.  First the setup:

```
d <- data.frame(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3)
attr(d, "test_attribute") <- "something"
d2 <- d
d
#>   a b c
#> 1 1 2 3
```

The `test` attribute is present:

```
attributes(d2) # contains $test_attribute [1] "something"
```

Now I want to remove the second column - but most ways destroy that attribute:

```
attributes(d2[, -2]) # it's gone
attributes(dplyr::select(d2, -2)) # it's gone
```

I found one way to preserve it:

```
d3 <- d2
d3[2] <- NULL
attributes(d3)
```

Why does the `test_attribute` get dropped in the first two cases, but not when using this last method?

Comment: It is a primitive function `[` .  The source code could give some indication -[do_subset](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/main/subset.c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`?Extract` describes this behavior.

> Subsetting (except by an empty index) will drop all attributes except names, dim and dimnames.